How to convert .fbx to frame images
I wanna to need help that i wanna to convert .fbx to video through script and i found a soluotion to do it through FFmpeg but it not supports .fbx so i need help in to get frame images so i can make video through ffmpeg or if i am goin in wrong direction you can help me
I tried to convert a .fbx file to .obj using three.js and then create a video from the .obj file, but it didn't work.
    <script>
        // Function to load FBX using FBXLoader
        function loadFBX(blob, loader, callback) {
            var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            loader.load(url, function(object) {
                callback(object);
            });
        }

        // Function to export THREE.Object3D to OBJ format using OBJExporter
        function exportToOBJ(object, callback) {
            var exporter = new THREE.OBJExporter();
            var result = exporter.parse(object);
            callback(result);
        }

        // Function to send OBJ file to PHP script
        function sendToPHP(objBlob, fileName) {
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('objFile', objBlob, fileName);

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', 'convert.php', true);
            xhr.onload = function() {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    console.log('Conversion successful:', xhr.responseText);
                } else {
                    console.error('Conversion failed:', xhr.responseText);
                }
            };
            xhr.send(formData);
        }

        // Function to convert FBX to OBJ
        function convertToOBJ() {
            var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
            var file = fileInput.files[0];

            if (file) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(event) {
                    var arrayBuffer = event.target.result;
                    var blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer]);
                    var loader = new THREE.FBXLoader();
                    loadFBX(blob, loader, function(object) {
                        exportToOBJ(object, function(objText) {
                            var objBlob = new Blob([objText], { type: 'text/plain' });
                            sendToPHP(objBlob, file.name.split('.')[0] + '.obj');
                        });
                    });
                };
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
            } else {
                alert('Please select an FBX file to convert.');
            }
        }
    </script>

<?php


// Check if form submitted and file uploaded
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_FILES["objFile"])) {
    $objFile = $_FILES["objFile"];
    $objFilePath = $objFile["tmp_name"];
    $outputVideo = 'output.mp4';

    // Execute FFmpeg command to convert OBJ to video
    exec("ffmpeg -i \"$objFilePath\" $outputVideo", $output, $returnCode);

    if ($returnCode === 0) {
        echo 'Conversion successful';
    } else {
        echo 'Conversion failed';
    }
} else {
    echo 'No OBJ file uploaded';
}
?>



Are you struggling with the JS part or with the PHP part?

Js part and now I changed the way of doing and i am making video from ffmpeg by frames but Facing issues in getting frames from .fbx
